# Datepicker is returning wrong date when set maximumDate

Tags: ios, swift, uidatepicker, swift4.2

I have a datepicker where I have set `maximumDate` as 2 years before

Today is 15/07/2019 so 2 years before it becomes 15/07/2017

Now when I open datepicker, automatically picker goes from today date (15/07/2019) to 15/07/2017 because I have set maximumDate as 2 years before

Now I don't scroll datepicker and click Done button where I read the picker date.

```
print("mDoneAction===\(mDatePicker.date)")
```

This print the date as below.

```
2019-07-15 12:26:17 +0000
```

Any idea why its giving me 2019 instead of 2017 as picker is already set on 15-07-2017 and not 15-07-2019.

Comment: I am guessing that that's just how it behaves, although I can't any documentation that explicitly talks about this behaviour. Just set `date` to be the same as the max date and it should work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From docs

```
open var date: Date // default is current date when picker created.
```

so setting `maximumDate` doesn't affect `date` , you need to set `date` also

```
let d = UIDatePicker()
let year2Before = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .year, value:-2, to: Date())!
d.date = year2Before
d.maximumDate = year2Before
```